# Не работает callback в inlineKeyboardMarkup из aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, callback

Написал код для продажи доступа в приват в тг, но никак не могу заставить работать callback адекватно, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
import config
from config import API_TOKEN

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#Каталог
mainkey = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
key = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Приват ", callback_data='vip')
mainkey.row(key)
#вернуться в каталог, покупка
startkey = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
back1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Вернуться назад", callback_data="back")
buy1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Приобрести доступ ", callback_data="buy")
startkey.row(back1,buy1)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def starting(message:types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Приветствую тебя, {message.from_user.username}")
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Чтобы ознакомиться с тарифами, выбери необходимый, нажав на соотвествующую кнопку", reply_markup=mainkey)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'vip')
async callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.edit_message_text("Приватка - это канал с частыми обновлениями и тд ",
    chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
    reply_markup="startkey")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Хочу сделать замечание, что в aiogram используется `call.from_user.id`

Comment: Так а чего вы в `edit_message_text` `"startkey"` в кавычки взяли?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token="Ваш токен")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Каталог
mainkey = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
key = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Приват ", callback_data='vip')
mainkey.row(key)
# вернуться в каталог, покупка
startkey = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
back1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Вернуться назад", callback_data="back")
buy1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Приобрести доступ ", callback_data="buy")
startkey.row(back1, buy1)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def starting(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Приветствую тебя, {message.from_user.username}")
    await message.answer("Чтобы ознакомиться с тарифами, выбери необходимый, нажав на соотвествующую кнопку",
                         reply_markup=mainkey)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'vip')
async def call_back(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_text("Приватка - это канал с частыми обновлениями и тд ", reply_markup=startkey)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Во первых, вы в обработке инлайн-клавиатуры пропустили def. Во вторых, `reply_markup="startkey"` определяйте без кавычек. Отправку сообщений пользователем можете реализовать как в моем коде выше. В функции Вы определили `call: types.CallbackQuery` но для изменений сообщений Вы его не использовали.

Советую прочтите документацию, пройдите уроки по азам.